# What would you know and what you would not know if you generated MD5 hash values for two files and they do not match?

Tags: file, archive

What would you know and what would you not know if you generated MD5 hash values (checksums) for two files and they do not match?

Answer (score 0):

You know that the two files differ if the checksums don't match.  That's about it.  Md5 is generally thought not to expose much information about the files.  So, for example, larger changes in the filesmay not make larger changes in the md5.
If the md5 happens to be the same, you don't actually know the files are the same.  [This demo](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/) demonstrates that md5 is an insecure hash because it is not very difficult to find two files that have the same hash.  With a hash like SHA256, you'd have a lot higher confidence the files are the same if the hashes are the same.
Unless you are specifically including metadata, ownership and modification time in the hash, knowing the hashes are the same does not mean that metadata is the same.